# How to pass a Javascript variable to Rails Controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Inside my index.html.erb

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
  var msg = "Hello World" ;
</script>
```

i need pass this var msg to my controller say  get_variable() method in my Post controller.

**Edit** : get javascript variable  msg in same index.html.erb as ruby variable 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you know about AJAX? If not, start reading up on it.

Comment: yes i do know it , can you please let me know to solve this issue , if you know it ?

Comment: Have you tried sending the variable via AJAX to `/posts/get_variable`…?

Comment: deceze i would like to render the variable in same page . Is it possible ?

Comment: Maybe you should clarify what it is you want first. Also, what's your knowledge of Javascript and AJAX? Are you starting from scratch, or are you just stuck on some specific detail?

Comment: I am implementing an auto save feature , where which i have variable which has to be saved into db with clicking on any link or button from javascript json object .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= link_to_remote, 'Message', :url=>{:controller=>'controller_name', :action=>'method_name'}, :with=> "'msg='+msg" %>
```

controller_name.rb

```
def method_name
  @message= params[:msg]
  puts @message # >> should be print "Hello World"

end
```

EDITED

```
<%= link_to_remote, 'Message', :url=>{:controller=>'controller_name', :action=>'method_name'}, :with=> "'msg='+msg" %>
<div id ='show_message'></div>
```

controller_name.rb

```
def method_name
  @message= params[:msg]
  render :update do|page|
    page.replace_html 'show_message', @message
  end
end
```

Comment: Salil , it did work but is there way in which i could display the variable in the same page  ,Instead of link_to_remote

Comment: I need without an link_to_remote not a evented action to display the content.

Comment: <%= periodically_call_remote ,:url=>{:controller=>'controller_name', :action=>'method_name'}, :with=> "'msg='+msg" ,  :frequency => '20' %>

but this is not proper way as after every 20 sec an ajax request is sent to the server